# ConcurrentModificationException thrown in here android sdk

Tags: android, here-api

Since upgrade to here android premium sdk v.3.9, I'm sometimes getting a ConcurrentModificationException when calling method Map#removeMapObjects(MapMarker).

Stacktrace :

```
java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next (ArrayList.java:573)
com.nokia.maps.MapImpl.d (MapImpl.java:2287)
com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map.removeMapObjects (Map.java:1634)
...
```

Is there something I can do to avoid this error ? Or is it a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs mostly when you are using a list/ map in app and updating ( add or deleting ) list/ map parallely while iterating them. So in order to perform those you use Iterator (Ref : Iterator examples). In list there is alternative option of copyOnWriteArrayList.